# How to explain this weird behaviour when programmatically setting margins to a view inside RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout inside a fragment that one of three tabs in a TabView. See this Screenshot - big pink square is my RelativeLayout:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX8xg.jpg)

The view that is inside it is the little blue square in the bottom right corner. Since the RelativeLayout is 300x300dp and the little square is 8x8dp, if I set its top and left margin to 292dp it ends up in that corner.
Now I want to change its position programmatically, but when I do it, my values keep getting divided by two. So if I change the margins from 292 to 292 it ends up in the center of the RelativeLayout, but if I set each to 292*2, it ends up back in the corner. 
Maybe there is someone who knows what is happening here?

This is my layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:width="40dp"
            android:height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="Test!" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/position_dot"
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginLeft="292dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="292dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</layout>
```

and this is the method I use to update the margins:

```js
 fun moveDotToCurrentPosition() {
        var params = positionDot.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

        params.topMargin = 292
        params.leftMargin = 292
       
        positionDot.layoutParams = params
    }
```

I tried to keep the code short and limited to what's relevant, if something important is missing please let me know and I put it in.
I'm writing this one in Kotlin, but Java answers will be helpful too.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all Java-code dimension values that are just raw `int` or `float` use **px** units, *not* dp. It is very likely that you are executing your code on an hdpi device. If so, your screen density means that `1dp` == `2px`, and this would explain why everything seems to be "divided by 2".

You can find your current screen density with code like this:

```
float density = [context].getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

And you can then multiply any `dp` values by this `density` to get the `px` values.

Alternatively, if you're working with dimensions that you've stored as `<dimen>` resources, you can just call:

```
int dimen = [context].getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.my_dimen);
```

Answer (score 0):

The values you are using to update your margins are in px size

```
params.topMargin = 292
params.leftMargin = 292
```

If you want to change them to 292dp you should load a dimen resource or multiply the value for displayMetric density

You can use the anko dip function

```
fun Context.dip(value: Int): Int = (value * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

Your code will look like this:

```
params.topMargin = dip(292)
params.leftMargin = dip(292)
```

Maybe this can fix your issue.